# Chrome Extension - Get Tab Preview Images

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension. I need to get a preview image for each tab. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tab API has captureVisibleTab functionthat you can use:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab

Do a simple search on stackoverflow to see how it works, I have answered many people regarding that feature.

If you want to alter that image after you capture it, then you can use HTML Canvas to do so.

Hope that helped